# xpath next button hidden

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

i am using xpath to go to the next page (for scraping)

but eventualy the "next" button hides how can i make sure that xpath doesnt select "next" again...

now its:

```
//A[.='Next']
```

the LI has the display none attribute

```
//LI[.='Next']
```

i tried

```
//LI[.='Next'][not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]//A[.='Next']
```

but it did'nt work...

whats the best way to solve this...

Comment: What's your Xml? You also seem to have to many // - this is not only slow but also select everything - try to be more precise in your queries to avoid bugs.

Comment: so whats the best way to get the //A[.='Next'] selected without it being hiddden ?

Comment: I don't know what is your xml document structur so I am not able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with

//LI[not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]/A[.='Next']